# Are QA certifications beneficial for career growth?

Tags: learning, career-development, certification

Some QA engineers, managers do QA certifications and think that it will be helpful to get a promotion or good salary hike in the current company or it will come handy when they switch companies.

Are certifications helpful in one's career growth?

Comment: welcome to the community!

Answer (score 1):

Certifications can be helpful in one's career growth, but they are not the only factor that determines an individual's career progression. It is important to keep in mind that certifications alone do not guarantee career advancement or a higher salary.

There are a number of factors that can contribute to career growth, including experience, skill level, and education. In the field of QA, it is important to have a strong understanding of testing methodologies, as well as experience with different types of testing tools and techniques.

That being said, certifications can be a good way to demonstrate a certain level of knowledge and expertise in a particular area. They can also be useful for individuals who are looking to switch careers or enter the QA field for the first time, as they can provide a foundation of knowledge and help individuals stand out from other candidates.

Ultimately, the value of certifications will depend on the individual and their specific career goals and needs. It is important to carefully consider whether obtaining a certification aligns with your career goals and whether the time and resources required to obtain the certification are worth the potential benefits.

Answer (score 0):

I am a senior QA in a US company, and I have yet to find anybody in any US company who has cared at all that I have a CTFL certification from the ISTQB. For what it's worth, I didn't get the certification to improve my job options in the US. I lived in Sweden for several years, and while the job I had there also didn't require ISTQB certification, it was not uncommon to see the certification referenced in European job postings.

Frankly, I have seen more interest from employers resulting from my Security+ certification. Sadly, that one's harder to get and more expensive (and has to be renewed at a cost every three years, as opposed to the CTFL which is a one-time thing).

That said, my experience around this is certainly US-centric. You don't mention where you are working, but I know the ISTQB has a bigger presence outside the US, so it may very well be that in other markets it makes more of a difference.

In any case, knowing the things that you have to know for a CTFL certainly won't do you any harm (though you might have to use slightly different vocabulary based on the specifics of any test-management tools you may be using).

Answer (score 0):

QA certifications can certainly be beneficial for one's career growth, but it is not a guarantee. The value that certifications bring to an individual's career depends on several factors, including the individual's current skills, experience, and the type of certification obtained.

While certifications can demonstrate an individual's knowledge of a particular tool or method, they do not necessarily indicate their level of proficiency or expertise. Many certifications available today focus primarily on testing theory and do not provide hands-on practical experience, which is a crucial aspect of QA. As a result, QA engineers may obtain a certification, but not have the practical experience to apply the knowledge they've learned in real-world scenarios.

Moreover, in today's fast-paced and constantly evolving software development industry, technology is rapidly changing, and certifications can quickly become outdated. This means that even if a QA engineer obtains a certification, it may become irrelevant within a few years, and they may need to obtain a new certification to stay current with the latest tools and methodologies.

Additionally, certifications alone may not be enough to advance one's career. Many companies also value hands-on experience, problem-solving skills, and the ability to work well in a team, among other things. Therefore, while certifications can be a factor in career growth, they should not be the sole focus. Instead, QA engineers should continually strive to improve their skills and knowledge through a combination of hands-on experience, training, and continued learning.

In conclusion, while certifications can certainly be beneficial for one's career growth, they are not the only factor that should be considered. It is important to have a well-rounded skill set, including hands-on experience, and to continuously strive to improve one's skills and knowledge.

Answer (score -2):

**Certifications** :

- Basically certifications are **playing vital role** when you **want to showcase or be stand out from others**
- Example :

  - May be stand out from others to **get short listed for interview** in multiple resume
  - You are planning to switch in different role or project with different stack then if you are certified for that particular skill then definitely you will **get an upper hand**
- I have to say, **only having certification is not enough**. You should be good/ hands on at those skills
- Your **work will & should speak louder** than just having certification
- Multiple certifications are **good to have for career advancement** but doesn't guarantee you

Comment: Please write in details what something wrong you observe, while vote downgrade. It will definitely make me improve my answer

Comment: I think it is because your answer is opinionated. Likely your emphasis on `playing vital role` is what triggers it. It is not valid per se. My take on it would be that certifications _in testing_ are useless in most cases. It depends on country, industry and company culture whether it is deemed important or not. In my experience it is mostly not. In all honesty: the question is also asking for an opinion. My 2 cent.
ps. As a side note: I find the many bold emphasizing in the text unneeded and shout-y.